# Use of N[Solve] as opposed to NSolve over the reals

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have an issue with a quartic function. Its four roots are real but I get different answers when I use `N[Solve[...]]` as opposed to `NSolve[...]`, where the second form produces the answer I expect.

```
N[Solve[4 + 22 σ - 9 σ^2 - 16 σ^3 + 5 σ^4 == 0]]

NSolve[4 + 22 σ - 9 σ^2 - 16 σ^3 + 5 σ^4 == 0]
```

N[Solve[...]] adds an imaginary term $6.07113*10^{-18}i$ which should not be here.

Do you know where it comes from and how I can prevent this unwanted result?

Comment: Use `Chop[]`. ${}$

Comment: "Do you know where it comes from...?" Examine the output of `Solve[4 + 22 \[Sigma] - 9 \[Sigma]^2 - 16 \[Sigma]^3 + 5 \[Sigma]^4 ==  0]`  -- Numericizing the result introduces rounding error.

Comment: `N@N[Solve[4 + 22 \[Sigma] - 9 \[Sigma]^2 - 16 \[Sigma]^3 + 5 \[Sigma]^4 ==  0], $MachinePrecision]` takes care of the rounding error, but you still have numbers of type `Complex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) over the domain [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html)

```
soln1 = Solve[
  4 + 22 σ - 9 σ^2 - 16 σ^3 + 5 σ^4 == 0, Reals]

(*  {{σ -> Root[4 + 22 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 1]}, {σ -> 
   Root[4 + 22 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 2]}, {σ -> 
   Root[4 + 22 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 3]}, {σ -> 
   Root[4 + 22 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 4]}}  *)

soln1n = soln1 // N

(*  {{σ -> -1.1524}, {σ -> -0.173507}, {σ -> 
   1.20467}, {σ -> 3.32124}}  *)
```

Alternatively, [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) the output of `Solve` to get [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects prior to using [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)

```
soln2 = Solve[
   4 + 22 σ - 9 σ^2 - 16 σ^3 + 5 σ^4 == 0] // 
  FullSimplify

(*  {{σ -> Root[4 + 22 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 1]}, {σ -> 
   Root[4 + 22 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 2]}, {σ -> 
   Root[4 + 22 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 3]}, {σ -> 
   Root[4 + 22 #1 - 9 #1^2 - 16 #1^3 + 5 #1^4 &, 4]}}  *)

soln2n = soln2 // N

{{σ -> -1.1524}, {σ -> -0.173507}, {σ -> 
   1.20467}, {σ -> 3.32124}}
```

The results are identical

```
soln1n === soln2n

(*  True  *)
```

Comparing with [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
NSolve[4 + 22 σ - 9 σ^2 - 16 σ^3 + 5 σ^4 == 0]

(*  {{σ -> -1.1524}, {σ -> -0.173507}, {σ -> 
   1.20467}, {σ -> 3.32124}}  *)
```